# tmux jump words as with zsh

Tags: terminal, iterm, zsh, tmux

I moved from just using zsh to using zsh inside tmux. As my terminal is iTerm2 for both combinations.

I have the following lines in my `.zshrc` to enable jumping words on a bare zsh command line using the ALT+arrow keys:

```
bindkey '[C' forward-word
bindkey '[D' backward-word
```

Sadly this is not working inside my tmux session.

> How can I jump words back and forth also in tmux using ALT + arrow
>   key?

What I tried so far:

1. `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on` [1](https://superuser.com/questions/360832/how-can-i-make-ctrlleft-right-keys-work-right-in-tmux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If found the solution here https://superuser.com/questions/427163/altarrow-moving-between-words-in-zsh-and-iterm2

You have to adjust the keybindings for ⌥ ← and ⌥→ inside iTerm2